# Call method in the end of web service call

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I have various service references in my solution.

I have to execute some method (that validates the data sent by WS is valid). And I have a method that do that.

My problem is that this method is spread by all my solution.

What is the best solution to call just in one place my method, instead off spreading them by all my solution?

Comment: are you rewriting the function everywhere ???

Comment: Yes! In the end of each WebService call...

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your service reference and any call to service with DI container.
By using interception. Look for unity interception for example. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647107.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can use Aspect Oriented Programming here. You can just create the attribute and apply it on all the service operations. Here is a good beginner guide: [AOP](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20526/Have-Fun-Again-With-Custom-Attributes-Part-1)